# Approach for the fake data generator that needs to maintain an order and referential integrity

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, python

I have a Python data generator capable of generating SQL-like relational data with primary and foreign key relationships, composite keys, and partial keys. Currently, I store this data in-memory using a plain dictionary (key-value) structure, where I sort headers every time I need to retrieve data to maintain alphabetical order. Some tables have hundreds of columns and hundreds of thousands of rows.

However, the implementation is becoming more complex due to the need to manage multiple data structures each time I generate data. Creating foreign and primary key relationships requires maintaining additional dictionaries for forward and reverse mapping (to track columns and aliases in dependent objects), extra sets to ensure primary key or 1-1 foreign key uniqueness, and index lists to preserve insertion order for composite keys (ensuring consistent row combinations so that partial keys are picked up from the same rows as their parts).

I also plan to introduce generated columns that depend on other columns in the same table (e.g., "full name" column derived from combining "name" and "surname"). This further complicates the implementation. Currently, I perform a topological sort before generating foreign key-dependent objects, but I'm considering switching to a column dependency approach to rely purely on column generation. With the use of a fake generator and seeds, I should be able to get the same generated data anyway.

I'm trying to find some approach to handle this complexity. I wonder if there is a suitable structure, like a tree, that could assist with this. Or maybe is there no other option than to continue maintaining the current structure?